# Position of Apostrophe in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to see if a log pattern layout has a timestamp/date field and its position in the layout when splitted by spaces. It seems like the position of apostrophe in the regular expression matters.

E.g. when I have the pattern `.*%d[ate]*\\{([\\w\\.'-\\:]+)}.*` it matches a layout of format `%X{IP} %X{field1} %X{field2} [%date{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} guid=%{guid} userId=%{userId} %msg%n`. However, when I interchange the `-` and `'` in the regular expression, I get a runtime error as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 19
.*%d[ate]*\{([\w\.-'\:]+)}.*
                   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2655)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2562)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2063)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
```

If you could explain the significance of the position of apostrophe, it would really help understand the concept of Regular expressions better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems to escape wrong characters inside character class. Notice that inside character class/set `[..]` the `-` character is used to create range of characters like `a-z`. But `.-'` is not correct range since index of `.` in Unicode Table greater than index of `'` in Unicode Table (just like `z-a` would be invalid).

To make `-` simple literal either escape it using `"\\-"` or place it in position where it can't be interpreted as part of *range*, like at start/end of character class (`[-...]` `[...-]`) OR *after* other ranges like `[a-z-1]` (which would represent `a-z` range, or `-`, or `1`).

Also you don't need to escape `.` or `:` in character class.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo for the explanation of the special character `-`. I've now simplified the expression to `.*%d[ate]*\\{([\\w.\\-':]+)}.*`.